# Why are there strange version numbers in some of the WSO2 Carbon POM files?

Tags: maven, build, maven-2, wso2

I've been trying to build the 3.2.2 and 3.2.3 tags of WSO2 Carbon from here using Maven 2:

https://wso2.org/repos/wso2/tags/carbon/3.2.2

https://wso2.org/repos/wso2/tags/carbon/3.2.3

However, the Maven pom.xml files throughout the directory trees beneath these tags still refer to version 3.2.0 in both cases - am I missing something obvious please?

When I try and analyse the results of both the builds using our in-house tool I get identical results in the two cases (and indeed results that are identical to those for 3.2.0), which makes me think I may be building 3.2.0 repeatedly by accident.

Comment: Have you compared the two tags with each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3.2.2 and 3.2.3 are point releases and typically involves bug fixes/optimizations that do not introduce new features to the 3.2.0 release. If a particular component do not have any fixes/changes, the version still be the older version, no new version is introduced. This is how the versions are handled.

Comment: Ah ok thanks. Why is the top-level version still 3.2.0 though? And the one in /core?

Comment: That is because all subsequent point releases should be within that minor release. Please refer http://commons.apache.org/releases/versioning.html for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You're not missing anything. It seems they did screw up. Maybe that was their intention, but then it doesn't make any sense at all (at least for me).

Comment: I'm not sure. I didn't analyze what's exactly there, but just take a look at POMs and tags' content. Probably you have to search for string `3.2.0` and replace it where you want.